# What is <router-view :key="$route.fullPath">?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm completely new to Vue.js and I think I have a bit of understanding of how a router works with things like:

```
<router-link to="/">
```

But I am not really understanding what the following line does:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

I believe `router-view` by itself makes sure the content is displayed but what does the key part mean?

Comment: Thank you soo much for asking this quistion!! :D 
I was looking now for hours for this feature!!!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

See [Special Attributes - key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)

> It can also be used to force replacement of an element/component instead of reusing it. This can be useful when you want to:

> - Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component

- Trigger transitions

[`$route.fullPath`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) is defined as

> The full resolved URL including query and hash.

If you bind `key` to `$route.fullPath`, it will always *"force a replacement"* of the `<router-view>` element / component every time a navigation event occurs.

As mentioned above, this is most probably done in order to trigger a transition / animation.

Comment: This is not updating the information in the view. I have to completely reload the page which is not a possibility for me.

Comment: @James there's probably something else you're missing. You should post a new question

Comment: Any way to get it programmatically with $router.push() ?

Comment: @Ashbay get _"what"_?

Answer (score 10):

In Vue-Router 4.0, this is implemented using a scoped slot. According to [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#forcing-a-transition-between-reused-views) the following is necessary to force a route to reload.

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
  <component :is="Component" :key="route.path" />
</router-view>
```

This is necessary for integrating with Vue 3 transitions.

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
  <transition name="fade">
    <component :is="Component" :key="route.path" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

**Note**: Putting the `:key="route.path"` directly on the `<router-view>` can cause subtle routing issues. Such as a route with a redirect triggering twice.