# VueJS reload if in the same route

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router, reload

We want that if we click on router-link which is the same page, the page will reload.

How can that be done? `watch->$route` doesn't invoke if the page stays the same

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847979/what-is-router-view-key-route-fullpath

Comment: @Jns The route stays the same, so this wont work

Answer (score 7):

If your need is just "refresh" the component due to a route parameter change, try this:

```
// define a watcher 
watch: {
    "$route.params.id"(val) {
      // call the method which loads your initial state
      this.find();
    },
},
```

where "id" comes from /myroute/:id and find() is a regular method.

Comment: a light on the js / vue / trip :clap :clap XD

Answer (score 5):

One of the options is to use key on RouterView:

```
<RouterView :key="whenThisVarChangeRouterViewWillBeRemounted" />
```

Just make sure to put key to something sensible if you don't want to reload on every router view change otherwise you could use:

```
:key="$route.fullPath"
```

which will guarantee to remount on every change to path.

Comment: should be 'route' not 'router'. but other than that it works very well! thank you

Comment: He is asking for clicking on router-link which is the same page, not pages with the same component. This won't work.

Comment: Fought with this for a few hours yesterday and this worked like a charm. Have some refinement on behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use  "beforeEnter" [Doc.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks)

```
   { 
     path: '/foo', component: Foo,
     beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
       /*
        todo check if to === from
        Warning!: location.reload()  completely destroy all vuejs stored states
        */
        window.location.reload()
        return next()
     }
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the hook will be called if the user is on the same page as the link he just clicked on

Answer (score 2):

work for me :)
set below code in router-view

**:key="$route.fullPath"**

```js
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"/>
```

Comment: really clean. i like it

Comment: very good! works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `@click` (or `@click.native`) on a `<router-link>` to execute your customs code when the user clicks on it.

Now this seems like a bad idea because you will have to use that method on every `<router-link>` in any component. A solution would be to wrap the `<router-link>` pseudo component with another component conveniently(!) called `routerLink` == `<router-link>`. I already do something similar with the original `<transition>` component and it works like a charm. *this doesn’t solve the problem of having to import that component and use it inside all components needing `<router-link>`, but it will mean you have a centralized place to add your custom logic for a clicking event and not repeating it again or modifying it in multiple places when you need to.*

I don’t have an available Vue.js project right now to test this on, so if the `@click(.native)` approach doesn’t work because `<router-link>` is a pseudo component, just apply the event listener to the newly created custom component.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for [Vue-Router Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

Comment: Thanks, tried it before - they won't fire if the route stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

**You never need to rerender the same component.** Same route means same component. So you can't listen to the route change in component as there is nothing trigger on same route. It is a performance waste to rerender the same thing. What you only need to execute some logic when someone clicking on the same route.

You would like to use [useEventBus](https://vueuse.org/core/useEventBus/) or  [provide / inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) to pass data to child component from parent. for example, reloading a query when clicking on the home link. but not re-render the whole child component.

Comment: If the page has a table fetched from the web, the user may want to just click on the same link to refresh the table rather than having a separate button to do that. And every link has also the similar content rendered based on web service provider. So every page should be reloadable.

Comment: @PuiHoLam If you want user clicks on the same link to refresh the page. You should use event to update the change instead of rebuilding whole page. Never reload the page/component.

Comment: When you change data on the component, it rerenders anyway. It's still much faster than the user pressing F5 out of frustration. The problem is development time where you need to code a lot of stuff for parent and children communication, esepcially when they are router links. I do have a solution that requires minimal coding for refreshing the page.

Comment: @PuiHoLam if you concern the developer time, and that is. but once you know how to use event bus to refresh the data, it won't you take you much time to develop it. and least you can wrap it as a function and reuse it on pages you need.

Comment: It isn't just that. Clicking on a link and seeing the page refresh has always been the default behaviour that internet users expect from a web browser. You'd make a refresh button for refreshing only the table data if you're concerned about that. Users may expect new things to happen to the page after the page refresh, not just the data.

Answer (score -1):

If you can modify `route-link` to `this.$router.push` in a component, and if you don't want to reload whole page like `window.location.reload()`, consider push a not existing route, then push the same route immediately.

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'not existing' })
this.$router.push({ name: yourRouteName })
```

side effect: Vue will warn: `[vue-router] Route with name 'not existing' does not exist` in console.

Comment: How would this affect browser history and the URL?