# what does this.$root means in a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a main App.vue component. in there, I have the following code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testVariable:false
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <VApp :dark="testVariable:false"
    <div id="app">
      <RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />
    </div>
  </VApp>
</template>
```

Then in one of the components, I have the following code:

```
data() {
    return {
      testVariable: this.$root.$children[0].testVariable,
    }
  },

methods: {
    darkModeToggle(e) {
      this.$root.$children[0].testVariable = e
    },
  },
```

Question 1) What does this.$root and this.$root.children mean? is `this.$root` always App.vue component(because App.vue is the parent of all components).  is `this.$root.children` the children of this App.vue component which means all other components will be in `this.$root.children` array?

Question 2) What does this line mean?`<RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />` . I mean why do we pass `:key="$route.fullPath"?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this.$root

- The root Vue instance of the current component tree. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root

this.$root.children

- The direct child components of the current instance. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children

is this.$root always App.vue component ?

- No. `App.vue` has a parent component, it's the `new Vue(...)` in main.js . so the `new Vue(...)` is the actual `$root`

is this.$root.children the children of this App.vue component which means all other components will be in this.$root.children array?

- `.children` are the DIRECT child components, NOT THE DESCENDANT. In this case, `$root` only has 1 direct child, which is `App.vue`

What does this line mean? . I mean why do we pass :key="$route.fullPath"?

- it's explained nicely in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52848095/5599288

Comment: SO this.$root will always be new Vue instance written in main.js ? doesn't matter from which component I call it right?

Comment: Will this be same in Nuxt?