# Force reload on same route diferent query parameter VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to reload the page component when user clicks on from the edit page, the router doesn't reload and the old edit values remain.

```js
{
  path: "/products/new",
  component: ProductPage,
  meta: {
    breadcrumb: [
      { name: "Home", link: "/home" },
      { name: "Products", link: "/products" },
      { name: "New Product" }
    ]
  }
},
{
  path: "/products/:id",
  component: ProductPage,
  meta: {
    breadcrumb: [
      { name: "Home", link: "/home" },
      { name: "Products", link: "/products" },
      { name: "Edit Product" }
    ]
  }
}
```

is there any way we reload the page component when two pages have same Component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847979/what-is-router-view-key-route-fullpath)

Comment: You could pass property(s) to the component based on the current route ([see here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)), so you can react to changes in them.

Comment: When you use the same component, Vue tries to reuse it instead of creating it again. To treat them as distinct and create the component again when the route changes you'll have to add a `key` special attribute to the `<RouterView>` component like so: `<RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" />`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$router.go()`...

`this.$router.go({path:'/products', params:{id:id}})`

Answer (score 0):

`this.$router.go({path:'/products', params:{id:id}})` doesn't work on Vue version 2 and above. I found a workaround if anyone else is having similar issues. Use

```
this.$router.push({path:'/products', params:{id:id}}, this.onCompleteReload)
```

And then have the function onCompleteReload like below:

```
onCompleteReload () {
if (this.existingData) {  // Some condition to make sure we are reloading from same route with different parameter.
  this.$router.go(0)
}
```

}