# How to forceUpdate vue data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using vuejs with laravel and I have links for next and previous pages while url is changing but new data won't show.

## Code

`Controller`

```
$verse = Chapter::where('slug', $slug)->with(['verses', 'book'])->first();
$next = Chapter::where('id', '>', $verse->id)->first();
$previous = Chapter::where('id', '<', $verse->id)->first();
return response()->json([
  'verses' => $verse,
  'next' => $next,
  'previous' => $previous,
]);
```

`component`

```
<div v-if="previous !== null" :v-model="previous" class="bible-nav-button previous">
    <router-link :to="`/${testament_slug}/${book_slug}/${previous.slug}`">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> <span>Previous</span>
    </router-link>
</div>
<div v-if="next !== null" :v-model="next" class="bible-nav-button next">
    <router-link :to="`/${testament_slug}/${book_slug}/${next.slug}`">
        <span>Next</span> <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </router-link>
</div>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "books",
        data() {
            return {
                url: window.location.origin + "" + window.location.pathname,
                title: '',
                testament_slug:'',
                book_slug: '',
                slug: '',
                verses: [],
                next: '',
                previous: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getBooks: function(){
                this.testament_slug = this.$route.params.testament_slug
                this.book_slug = this.$route.params.book_slug
                this.slug = this.$route.params.slug
                axios.get('/api/'+this.$route.params.book_slug+'/'+this.$route.params.slug+'/'+this.$route.params.slug).then((res) => {
                    this.verses = res.data.verses
                    this.title = "Read Bible: " +res.data.verses.book.name+ " " +res.data.verses.name
                    this.next = res.data.next
                    this.previous= res.data.previous
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
            },
            myHTML: function(item) {
                return "<strong>"+item.number+"</strong> "+item.body+" ";
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getBooks();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Any idea how i can fetch my new data?**

Comment: My recommendation will be to use vuex(store). This way you can store your data in state then just map the state to any of your component

Comment: @livresonltc I've never done that (as i'm newbie with vue) wuld you mind share sample as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:key` props in `<router-view>` tag and use the route fullpath.

`<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>`

I used to put a watcher of the current route and call function to fetch data, but I just found that we can do this after watching vue-router tutorial from vueschool.

Also see the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847979/what-is-router-view-key-route-fullpath)

Comment: I have my loop like `<div v-for="item in verses.verses" :key="item.id">` then when i used your solution i got this error `Duplicate keys detected: '/url/xyz/'. This may cause an update error.`

Comment: ok i found my mistake (should be add to `router-view`) there is small issue, while my next button works fine my previous button just jumps to page one except previous page, any idea?

Comment: @mafortis maybe because your query to get previous page `Chapter::where('id', '<', $verse->id)->first();` makes it fetch first id. Add `->orderBy('id', desc)` before calling `->first()` should solve your problem.

Comment: yeah for previous we can use orderby but for next will result same issue as previous button. Thanks man it's solved completely now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple options:

1) Change the "previous" and "next" to @click actions that call the fetch function again and then update the URL (like this this.$router.push()).

```
<span @click="goNext(/* needed arguments here */)">Next</span>

goNext (/* params here */) {
     //set whatever variables you need to
     this.$router.push(/* route as string here */)
     this.getBooks()
}
```

2) Since you're using the router, use guards to update every time the URL changes:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

```
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
     this.getBooks()
     next()
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks fr the answer I've tried no.2 but nothing changed here is screenshot how i did it https://ibb.co/rw5m0yG  would you mind give sample of no.1 as well? maybe that works

Comment: The route guard does not go inside "methods". It is its own property. Please read the documentation I sent you carefully. I will update the answer for option 1.

Comment: unfortunately i wasn't able to make it with either way :/