# Vue render a component two times

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I logged in the app and select edit some item, they make a $router.push to the edit view, the problem is that they render the component two times, I figured this out by doing a console.log on mounted(){}.. However, if I reload the page and click edit other time they make the render correctly, only one time.

This is the relevant code:

```
//listItemsView script
editItem(item) { 
  this.$router.push({ name: 'editPolicy', params:{policyTest: item}})
},

//editItemView script
export default {
  props:{
      policyTest:{
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      }
   mounted(){
      console.log(this.policyTest);
      console.log('entra');  
   },
 }
```

```
 //router script
 {
    path: '/editPolicy/', 
    name: 'editPolicy',
    component: () => import('../views/policies/editPolicy.vue'),
    props: true,
    meta:{requireAuth:true}
  }
  
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  if(user !== null){
    user.getIdTokenResult(true)
        .then(function ({
          claims
        }) {
          if (to.name === 'NewClient' && !claims.permissions.includes('Agregar Cliente')) {
            next({name: 'notFoundPage'});
          }else{
            //In this case the router execute this next()
            next()
          }
        })
    } else {
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)) {
        next({name: 'SignIn'});
      } else { 
        next()
      }
  }
})
```

```
//html
<td class="text-left">
   <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">fas fa-edit</v-icon>
</td>
```

[image: console.log result]

Comment: Looks like Vue is trying reusing the component when changing routes. You could try using `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">` like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52848095/10387396

Comment: It mounts two times, my guess is that there two different instances, maybe check the trace. But also you can key those components to make sure those are reused. Simply write debugger in mount or log.error new error. To get an idea what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem, I'm use firebase authentication and in the main.js i'm detecting the user state change and for error i was creating two vue instances, one when start up the App and other when the user attemp to make their logging.. solved, thanks