# Vue 3 and Vue Router 4 How to pass prop when using router-view only for specific component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I have basic routing and props working but the way I have it, the msg prop will be sent to every component loaded by the router? Is there a way around this?

App.vue is my base component

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
        <router-view msg="Hello Foo"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'App',
};
</script>
```

This is my HomePage.vue component

```html
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'HomePage',
    props: {
        msg: String,
    },
};
</script>
```

And here is my routes.js

```js
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'HomePage',
        path: '/',
        component: HomePage,
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

I would like to know is there a way to dynamically send different props depending on which route/component is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure a [route meta field](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields) just for specific routes:

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import HomePage from '@/views/HomePage.vue'

export default createRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'HomePage',
      path: '/',
      component: HomePage,

       
      meta: {
        msg: 'Hello Foo',
      },
    },
    ⋮
  ],
})
```

And use it in your component via `$route.meta` directly in the template:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <h2>Home</h2>
  <h3>{{ $route.meta.msg }}</h3>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-router-meta-fields?file=src%2Fviews%2FHomePage.vue)

Or via [`useRoute().meta`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute):

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()
const msg = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  msg.value = route.meta.msg
})
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-router-meta-fields?file=src%2Fviews%2FAbout.vue)

Comment: Research yesterday and last night led me to finding a ton of different ways to do this, but your answer is clean, simple, has great code examples and to the point answers the question. I'm working on listing other options to leave here as another answer for future travelers. Thanks for the OP edit BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'key' property to router-view so every route change force update on msg prop, you have to put dynamic value for msg prop based on route.

But you can do it better: use beforeEach hook provided be vue-router and add dynamic params based on route name.

Adding the Code Example

### // Add Dynamic Title for Pages

```
// Assume we have a routes array
const routes = [
  {
  path: "/",
  name: "home",
  component: HomeView,
  meta:{
  title: 'Home'
  }
  },

  {
  path: "/hotels",
  name: "hotels",
  component: HotelsView,
  meta:{
  title: 'Hotels'
  }
  },
  {
  path: "/hotels/:id",
  name: "hotel",
  component: HotelView,
  meta:{
  title: 'Single Hotel'
  }
  },
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
// Add Dynamic Title for Pages
document.title = `${to.meta.title}`
next()
})
```

Comment: Good suggestions that led me into a lot of research and testing. Some example code would be helpful for future readers but it wasn't too difficult to find in the docs once I knew what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

The use case here seems a little silly but it will work for any data that needs to be passed to a component as a prop or param be it static or dynamically set per route so I think it is good information to know.

## Some Options:

### 1. [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

Answer by @tony19 Has other purpose according to the docs such as using along with the beforeEach [Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) for an authentication check but it works well for simply adding a field/value to the specific route that can be accessed from the component.

I could also just add a prop to the route as long as I don't need to do anything dynamic with it. Props can be passed in each route but not accessed in a beforeEach hook like to.meta and to.params can.

### 2. Params and Dynamic Routing in the routes.js File

[Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

[Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

[Optional Route Parameters](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#optional-parameters)

[Router Views v-slot](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view-s-v-slot)

As suggested by @Witold we can use the beforeEach hook and add params dynamically. Here is what I came up with based on some research. setParams() is just a real simple way of setting params that could probably be done better but it works for demo.

For `<router-view>` in App.vue I'm using the new v-slot way. The docs make it look like it is only neccessary for transitions and v-for and the old method even without a key attribute works for what I'm doing here. In fact all 3 methods shown in my App.vue work fine for this use case. But from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847979/what-is-router-view-key-route-fullpath) and from some little info I saw in some github issues, I think the new way with v-slot is the preferred way and covers all the bases for more complex situations. Not 100% sure yet though.

In routes.js the `/` route gets the 2 params set by my setParams method.
`props: true` causes the params to be copied to props. However in HomePage.vue I've only declared msg2 and msg3(set in App.vue) so msg1 has to be accessed as a param and msg2 is a prop. msg1 will show a warning in console if you try to access it as a prop since it was not declared in the props:{} property of the component.

The `/:foo?` route is a regular route param so I make sure not to overwrite it in my setParams method so it is also available in HomePage.vue as a param

### 3. Dynamic Setting Props in App.vue

I'm not sure about older versions but the current version of Vue Router works asynchronously, so life cycle hooks will not work to access $route.name. I could not find this in the docs but found the same repeating situation several times in closed github issues. We can either use something like beforeEach in the routes file as in option 2. Or we can create a watcher to watch for the change in $route.name which is what I've done for msg3.

msg3 is stored as data in App.vue will trigger the re-render of the message when it changes. The watcher calls setMsg() which is another simple, non-realistic js method that works for the demo. changeMsg() is just a method for the button in HomePage.vue to see that it works any time msg3 is changed.

Instead of a watcher you can use router.isReady() in the main Vue instance.

app or main.js

```js
//...imports and stuff
const app = Vue.createApp(App);

app.use(router);

router.isReady().then(() => app.mount('#app'));
//app.mount('#app');
```

I think this waiting for the router to be ready would cause a flash of white screen though I'm not seeing it in this quick simple demo. Loading the page and watching for the route.name change would avoid that.

### Some Other Ideas

We can set an array, object, or array of objects globally on window or better yet, as a Vue global accessible by all components.

In app.js

```js
app.config.globalProperties.$pageMessages = {};
```

Then access it in App.vue and set dynamic messages. Then access the global on the page component to retrieve and display the message without passing it as a prop or param.

We could also use axios or fetch API in the root app or in the page component to retrieve messages just like any other data from a database.

routes.js

```js
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'HomePage',
        path: '/',
        component: HomePage,
        props: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'HomePage',
        path: '/:foo?',
        component: HomePage,
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

const setParams = name => {
    // if matches name, set params
    if (name === 'HomePage')
        return {
            msg1: 'Hello I am a param',
            msg2: 'Hello I am a param/prop',
        };

    return {}; // empty object if no match
};

router.beforeEach(to => {
    // copy original params if they exist so I don't overwrite
    const params = { ...to.params, ...setParams(to.name) };
    to.params = params;
});

export default router;
```

HomePage.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <!--msg1 accessible as param but not as prop-->
        <p>{{ this.$route.params.msg1 }}</p>
        <!--as a prop, msg1 warning in console because not set in props:{}-->
        <p>{{ msg1 }}</p>
        <!--msg2 prop copied from params-->
        <p>{{ msg2 }}</p>
        <!--msg3 prop dynamic set in App.vue-->
        <p>{{ msg3 }}</p>
        <!--foo is a regular route param-->
        <p>{{ this.$route.params.foo }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'HomePage',
        props: {
            msg2: String,
            msg3: String,
        },
    };
</script>
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <router-view :msg3="this.msg3"></router-view> -->
        <!-- <router-view :key="$route.path" :msg3="this.msg3"></router-view> -->

        <router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
            <component :is="Component" :key="route.path" :msg3="this.msg3" />
        </router-view>

        <button @click="changeMsg">Change msg3</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',

        data() {
            return {
                msg3: '',
            };
        },

        watch: {
            '$route.name'(name) {
                this.msg3 = this.setMsg(name);
            },
        },

        methods: {
            setMsg(name) {
                if (name === 'HomePage')
                    return 'Hello I am a dynamically set prop for the home page';
                if (name === 'AboutPage')
                    return 'Hello I am a dynamically set prop for the about page';

                return '';
            },

            changeMsg() {
                this.msg3 = 'foobar';
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```