# Vue Router: Browser navigation button back not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue App i use the `vue router` to computed navigate from a *create page* to *edit page*.

The use case:

- create a ressource
- on success go to edit page

The use case above works fine.

Further use case:

- click on the button *browser back*

**Expected**: default create page content (create form)
**Actual**: Route has changed, content remains (edit form)

So it seems, the router history fails.

*router/index.ts*

```
import {createRouter, createWebHashHistory} from 'vue-router';
...
import testRoute from  './test_route'

const routes = [
  ...
  testRoute
]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
})

export default router;
```

*router/test_r
oute/index.ts*

```
import TestPage from "@/module/test/page";
...
import TestDetail from "@/module/test/view/detail";

const route = {
    component: TestPage,
    path: "/test/page",
    redirect: ...,
    children: [
        ...,
        {
            path: 'create-test', 
            name: "testDetailCreate",
            component: TestDetail
        },
        {
            path: 'edit-test/:id?', 
            name: "testDetailEdit",
            component: TestDetail
        }
    ]
}

export default route;
```

*~/detail/index,ts*

```
export default defineComponent({
  ...
  methods: {
    ...,
    createHandling() 
      {
        ...
        fetch("%create-resource%", {
          ...
        }).then((resp) => {
          ...
          return resp.json()
        }).then(data => {
          // set store vars
          ...
          this.$router.push({name: 'testDetailEdit', params: {id: data.id}});
          // location.href = "/edit-test/" + data.id;
          // location.reload()
        })
      },
  }
})
```

I try above code with `location.href` and `this.$router.push`, both with the same **unexpected result**.

So my question is, why the ***vue router history* doesn't work within the *browser navigation*?**

Comment: The whole case is not shown. You potentially need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847979/what-is-router-view-key-route-fullpath . Does this work differently if you navigate back with router.push?

Comment: both routes go to the same component, so for efficiency the same component instance is reused, lifecycle hooks are not rerun, data is not reinitialized, etc..  you can get around this by reacting to the route path in a watcher or using a nav guard such as beforeRouteUpdate to update and/or reset your page content.  It's actually talked about [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#Reacting-to-Params-Changes) in the documentation regarding using the same route with different params, but I believe same thing happens any time you navigate to the same component.